# Why is my render coming out blurry?

Tags: rendering, resolution

When I try to render a wave, it keeps being rendered in extremely low quality. I'm not sure exactly which setting is causing this, but increasing the `render`and `viewport` sampling don't seem to help.

[image: render-view]

Comment: please provide your blend file - could be many reasons....

Comment: [here is a link to the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IUH0WK1ZFme6zHVdWVleDCzOixo4acg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your ocean modifier the render resolution is 3. To get a similar result to your viewport you should at least raise it to 32 too.

Then you get:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have modifiers on your cube. Please check if the render-visibility of your modifier is enabled.

[image: Render enabled]

Comment: It looks like the render-visibility is enabled [there is a camera icon next to cube > modifiers > ocean]

Comment: Then try increasing the subdiv render levels,maybe it's high in the viewport but 0 or 1 in the render